# how to get a URL in route parameter in Silex

Tags: php, url, parameters, routes, silex

How can I pass a URL in a Silex-app?

My given specification is:

```
http://mysilex.app/http://anotherurl.com
```

So, I would like to use it in my app like this:

```
$app->get('/{url}', function ($url) {
  //do awesome things with $url(=http://anotherurl.com)
  return $url;
});
```

Is that possible in Silex?

Comment: `http://anotherurl.com` needs url encoded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `.*` pattern for `url` parameter

```
$app->get('/{url}', function ($url) {
  //do awesome things with $url(=http://anotherurl.com)
  return $url;
})
->assert('url', '.*');
```